# SQL Server Specific term full text search is not working

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, c#

I'm trying to perform an specific term full-text search in SQL Server. It looks like the way to do it is by wrapping the keywords in double quotes, which I'm doing in my app:

```
Query = "\"" + model.SearchString + "\""
```

However, when I perform the query against the database with a term such as "foo bar", it returns every occurrence of "foo" and "bar" inside the database. The expected result is that the database should return only the records that have "foo bar" specifically. This is the query:

```
SELECT o.OpinionDocumentId
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(OpinionDocuments, Html, '"foo bar"') AS KEY_TBL
LEFT JOIN dbo.OpinionDocuments AS o ON o.OpinionDocumentId = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
WHERE o.Date BETWEEN @from AND @to
```

What could be the reason why this query is not returning the results from an specific set of keywords?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query actually needs to use two properties of the `CONTAINSTABLE` function-

`<maximum distance>` and `<match_order>`.

Using

`CONTAINSTABLE(OpinionDocuments, HTML, 'NEAR((Foo, bar), 0, TRUE)') AS KEY_TBL`

Specifies to find "Foo" near "Bar" with 0 search objects between (`<maximum distance>`  ", 0,") and in the order specified (`<match_order>` ",TRUE")

Comment: I am not the OP, but I've got a question about your suggestion. Are you saying that wrapping a search, to `CONTAINSTABLE` in quotes doesn't actually perform an exact phrase lookup? What you're doing with `NEAR` is what I thought the quotes did, already. Is this not correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The full-text indicies actually use "language tokens" (words, phrases) as a basis. For a brief overview of this, you can check out this article:        https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/